# Find moment generating function of Y = $e^X$

Tags: probability, moment-generating-functions

Let $X$ ~ $N(0,1)$ and $Y=e^X$. Find the moment generating function of Y.

I think I first need to find the cdf of Y. So I take:

$F_Y(y) = P(Y \le y) = P(e^X \le y) = P(X \le ln(y)) = F_X(ln(y))$

I think that part is correct. Now I get a little confused.

I think $M_Y(t) = Ee^{tX} = \int^{ln(y)}_{-\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^\frac{x^2}{2} e^{tx}\,dx $

Does that look right?

Comment: Is the notation clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $Y$ has lognormal distribution $\ln\!\mathcal{N}(0,1)$. Write $X=\ln Y$, we get $$\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{1}{y}.$$ It follows then
        \begin{align*}
  f_Y(y)&=f_X({\ln Y})\cdot\left|\frac{1}{y}\right|\\
  &=\frac{1}{y\sqrt{2\pi}}\cdot\exp\left(-\frac{(\ln y)^2}{2}\right).
  \end{align*}
Hint 2: If we change the variable back to $X$, then 
        \begin{align*}
  M_Y(t)&=E[e^{te^x}]\\
  &=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\exp\left(te^x-\frac{x^2}{2}\right)\,dx.
  \end{align*}
which is divergent if $t>0$, why? Consider Taylor series of $e^x$: $$e^x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}$$ and the fact that $$\int_0^\infty e^{tx^3}\,dx$$ diverges for all $t>0$.

Comment: So I think this is the integral I need to evaluate: $M_Y(t)=\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \frac{1}{y\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\frac{lny^2}{2}} e^{ty}\,dy$

Comment: Any ideas on how to get started? I think I can move the $e^t$ out front and I'd like to make a cancellation with the $f_X(lny)$ term (since by itself in the integral it equals 1) but I still have a $\frac{1}{y}$ and an $e^y$ left over

Comment: @kbball: more hints!

Answer (score 1):

There's a little confusion in your writing.

*Hint*: $M_Y(t)=\mathbb{E}(e^{tY})=\int_?^? e^{ty}f(y)dy$ where $f(y)$ is the density function of $Y$ and is equal to $\frac{d}{dy}F_Y(y).$